Translating "You wanna bet?"

Bob: "What are you watching?"
Sally: "Oh it's a French New Wave film. You've probably never heard of it."
Bob: "You wanna bet?"

In this dialogue, "You wanna bet?" means that Bob thinks Sally is wrong (i.e., Bob thinks he probably has heard of the film and wants Sally to share the name of it). What would be the most natural way to express this in Chinese? The translation needn't involve betting. In fact, in English it is exceedingly rare for this phrase to be followed up by any actual betting--it's just challenging the statement of the other person. It would be equally natural to say "Don't be so sure!" or "I wouldn't be so sure about that!"

Google: You wanna bet? = 你想打賭嗎？
My translation:
"You wanna bet?" =  "你敢打賭嗎？" (do you dare to bet on it? --> Don't bet on things you don't know for a fact)
"You wanna bet?" = "你肯定？" (Are you sure?)

If I say "Ya wanna bet" then I'm daring the other person to try to prove me wrong and suggesting I'm confident if they do try they will lose, so it feels like 你敢打賭吗 ought to be closest but is this something Chinese people would naturally say? I've heard people say 你敢肯定?

Tang, is this something you have said in normal conversations? It's very hard for me to tell how normal-sounding it is.

你敢打賭吗 is  normal in written Chinese; 你肯定? is normal colloquially

To challenge the other person's mockery (戲謔), I would say "(你)敢賭吗?". "你肯定?" is often used to double confirm the rightfulness of a statement made by another person.

It can be 赌吗 or 赌不赌, although it’s not rare if this ends up with actual betting.
You can even include your bet. It can be unrealistic (if you don’t really want to bet or you’re emotional/childish) like 一个亿赌不赌 or a value bet (if you do want to win something) like 赌一顿饭吗 or 一百块赌吗.
If you simply want to challenge or disagree with someone, there are many ways. A famous one is 真的吗？我不信。 (Really? I don’t believe it.) It’s originally considered offensive when 鲁豫 said it but now it has become a funny meme, especially if you say it in a slow and innocent way.

Big Bob is self-confident, sure in the knowledge that he knows everything there is to know about French New Wave films.
鲍勃: 怎么可能? (老鲍勃没听说过)
